# ComboBox bindings need different Datacontexts

Tags: wpf

Im relatively new to WPF and I'm stuck on what would seem like a relatively common scenario within a VMMV environment. It centres around setting the datacontext for a combobox.

I have a view model with

- a string property
- an XmlDataProvider property.

My plan was to use the XmlDataProvider to populate the combobox items and the string property would be bound to the SelectedItem of the combo box.

In my XAML, the top level grid sets the DataContext as the ViewModel.
Within the grid I have a combobox defined as below

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CategoryCombo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" 
Margin="54,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="233"  
ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/OccupationCategory/@name}" 
DataContext="{Binding myProvider}"/>
```

The list is populating correctly. My problem is that in order to get the XmlDataProvider
to work properly, I needed to bind the DataContext of the combobox to the XMLDataProvider property within my Viewmodel.

As far as I can see this means I cannot now bind the SelectedItem to the String property within my ViewModel. This would require me to have the Datacontext set back to the viewmodel.

Note. I did experiment with various variations of XAML which would not force me to set the dataContext of the wholecombobox to the XmlDataProvider, but none worked. The XAML below failed to populate the list. From the binding error it seems like in this case the datasource is still pointing to the viewmodel, not the XMLDataProvider

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CategoryCombo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" 
Margin="54,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="233"  
ItemsSource="{Binding myProvider, XPath=/OccupationCategory/@name}" />
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, you do not have to bind only into DataContext, one way is to bind to grid dataContext.

```
SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=DataContext.YourStringProperty}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Clearly I've got more learning to do on WPF.